# Regular expression and Right Regular grammar for decimals starting with 1 ending with 9?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I was trying to do the following:

> Consider the set of all strings over the alphabet {0,1,2,9} that are decimal numbers beginning with 1 and ending with 9 and having exactly one decimal point (.). For example 12.9, would be a valid decimal number while 0.129 would be not since it does not begin with 1.

but it didn't seem to work:

```
1(0|1|2|9)*.(0|1|2|9)*9
```

or

```
S::=1X
X::=E|0X|1X|2X|9X|Y
Y::=.Z
Z::=E|0Z|1Z|2Z|9Z|A
A::=9
```

Why? Whats the correct answer?

Comment: The alphabet is mentioned twice in the question.  Do you have two copies of decimal numbers that are concatenated?  If so, take: S -> S'S', where S' generates a decimal number A.B, where A -> 1N and B ->N9, and where N contains 0 or more digits.

Comment: @AshwinGanesan somehow the copy pasting screwed that up. Only 1 alphabet, its been updated.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is correct, however, your grammar isn't. Assuming $E = \varepsilon$, you can derive words like $S \to \mathtt{1}\,X \to \mathtt{1}\,\varepsilon = \mathtt{1}$.

A right regular grammar might look like this:
\begin{align}
S &::= \mathtt{1}\,A\\
A &::= \mathtt{0}\,A \mid \mathtt{1}\,A \mid \mathtt{2}\,A \mid \mathtt{9}\,A \mid B\\
B &::= \mathtt{.}\,C\\
C &::= \mathtt{0}\,C \mid \mathtt{1}\,C \mid \mathtt{2}\,C \mid \mathtt{9}\,C \mid D\\
D &::= \mathtt{9}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression for your language is:
$$ 1(0\cup\ 1\cup 2\cup 9)^*.(0\cup\ 1\cup 2\cup 9)^*9.$$